# Difficulties with book class and beginning of chapters

Tags: page-breaking, double-sided, books, layout

I want to use the book class but I have issues with the formatting: In my understanding, new chapters should always start on a right page but somehow that is not the case in this example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    
\thispagestyle{empty}
I manually produce my own title page here but it should be a right page\\

\blindtext
    
\newpage 
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{\fill}
This should be on the back of the title page, i.e. a left page\\

\blindtext
    
\chapter{Test}
\blindtext
    
\tableofcontents
    
\chapter{Test 2}
\blindtext
    
\end{document}
```

The document starts with a left page unfortunately. And even after that, the chapters always start on the left instead on the right and before and after the table of content there are even white pages introduced to make it start on the left. I tried \openright which didn't help. I also tried inserting an empty page in the beginning, which solves the issue for the title page and the next one but the chapter again starts on the left. I also tried \cleardoublepage, no difference.

Any ideas how to solve the problem?

Addition: I don't print the document or look at it with some twosided options. I just look at the margins from the pages. If a page has a bigger right margin it is a left page. Here is a picture of the first page

[image]

Comment: I can't confirm. How do you come to the idea that the first page is a "left" page?

Comment: As pst mentions, it is likely that you are showing your document in a dual display (2 pages side by side) and that your PDF viewing program does not place page 1 as a right hand side. If I remember correctly this was the case last time I tried it in Adobe Reader. My Evince PDF viewer for Linux, shows dual mode correctly and thus displays the first page with an empty left hand page (as it should)

Comment: @campa I just look at the margins, a bigger right margin means a left page

Comment: @daleif I just look at the margins, I am familiar with the issue in Adobe Reader

Comment: The margins are correct. `book` runs in twoside mode by default, and the outer (right hand) margin of the first page is larger than the inner margin of the same page. As it should be

Comment: Here's a general comment as well: If you are thinking about writing a book, it is very possible that you will be better of with another class than the standard `book`. Two popular choices are [`scrbook`] (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrbook) in the KOMA script family and [`memoir`] (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/memoir).

Comment: yes, that is the correct margins.

Comment: You might want to take a look in https://ctan.org/pkg/memdesign where Peter Wilson looks at book design and explains the concepts. For example in many designs if you place a left hand page next to a right handpage then the outer margin (left) on the left hand page and the outer margin (right) in the right hand page are the same, and the size of the combined inner margin is the same as the outer margin (Note this is not the default in the book class). Thus it is normal that the outer margin is larger than the inner margin.

Comment: @daleif But the first page shoulnd't be a left page in my opinion. And definitely, the chapters should start on the right (which I thought is standard as well) but this is really weird in this case

Comment: I'm sorry I wrote a confused and confusing comment. I didn't expect the questioner to have a contrary expectation on margins, so I didn't notice that mixup but thought it said something else. I'll clean up.

Comment: @mathstackuser it is not a left hand page. Do your self a favor and remove the `\thispagestyle`'s, the first page is page 1 and is by definition a right hand page. Please explain exactly why you think this is a left hand page.

Comment: "_If a page has a bigger right margin it is a left page._" This statement of yours is not generally true. The output is exactly as it should be, and the first page is a right page. You are absolutely entitled to not like it and you can change it if you want, but the output you are getting from TeX is the intended one.

Comment: @daleif For binding purposes, I think a left page should have a bigger right margin and the other way round for right pages. Maybe that's what created confusion

Comment: @campa How can I easily change that? I want to get the document printed and binded and think the inner margins (i.e. the right marign for a left page and the left margin for a right page) should be bigger

Comment: Use the `geometry` package to change the margins. We often set left and right margin to be the same, then binding eats some of the inner margin, giving the "illusion" of a larger outer margin and the document does not jump when you change page while viewing online.

Answer (score 1):

## Edit

After many comments it has become clear that the OP just wanted to adjust the margins of his/her document so that the inner margins are larger than the outer margins.

Please, do read up on the `geometry`-package: https://ctan.org/pkg/geometry

As for the margins, here's a quick example: The first page – as pst has said – is the right-hand page. You can visualize it like this:

```latex
\documentclass[twoside,openright,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[
    inner=5cm,
    outer=2cm
]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    
\thispagestyle{empty}
I manually produce my own title page here but it should be a right page.

\blindtext

\newpage 
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{\fill}
This should be on the back of the title page, i.e. a left page

\blindtext
    
\chapter{Test}
\blindtext
\blindtext[1]
    
\tableofcontents
    
\chapter{Test 2}
\blindtext
    
\end{document}
```

<del>You can see that the margin (e.g. for sidenotes) is on the right in just about every instance you've disputed:</del>

[image: all the right pages]

Comment: As a side note, a casual viewer might see your second image as page 2 of the output.

Comment: You mean I should include one more image? Done! Thanks for the hint.

Comment: It might be better, and perhaps make them smaller. No reason for them to be natural sized

Comment: @daleif, ah, I see, excellent idea, will do!

Comment: You are right but unfortunatley, this is not what I need. For binding purposed, I need a bigger margin on the inner sides (i.e. the right marign for a left page and the left margin for a right page)

Comment: @mathstackuser but that's just a question of one line in the code. Let me edit this for you. Brb …